# When taking screenshot for whole layout only visible listitems on screen are coming in bitmap

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, screenshot, viewgroup

I am trying to take a screenshot for whole view and sharing it via pdf or image.
Here is my layout view.

**activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    tools:context="com.tally.enjay.tallyandroid.activity.LedgerTransactionHistoryActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        style="@style/Base.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/DateTheme"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="01/04/17 - 31/03/18"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/current_date"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="vs."
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreyshred"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/previous_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/current_date"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/vs"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="01/04/16 - 31/03/17"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreyshred"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/DateTheme"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/amount">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_vch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/header_date"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Vch No. / Vch Type"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_amt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ledger_empty_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_data_available_for_this_ledger"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/table_header">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when i click on share button in toolbar it will open pop up menu to share image or pdf. On selection of image or pdf my method namely **shareViaPdfOrImage(String Selection)** is called where selection will contain string of PDF or Image aas per pop menu choice.

**activity.class**

```
     private void shareViaPdfOrImage(String selection) {
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();   //method called to take screen shot here is think my issues is happening.
            saveBitmap(bitmap, selection);

        }

       //This whole method is woking fine so i am not expnading it.
        private void saveBitmap(Bitmap myBitmap, String selection) {
            final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myappxyz";

            if (selection.equals("PDF")) {
                createPdf(myBitmap, dirPath);
            } else if (selection.equals("Image")) {
                createImage(myBitmap, dirPath);
            }


        }

 // My issues starts with this method
 private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        //View view = getWindow().findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        //  int width = view.getWidth();
        //  int height = view.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout mainView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        int childcount = mainView.getChildCount();
        Log.e("childCount", "==>" + childcount);

        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {

            View subview = mainView.getChildAt(i);

            if (subview instanceof SwipeRefreshLayout) {
                Log.e("subview is swipe", "==>" + i);
                bitmaps.add(getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(listView));

            } else {
                bitmaps.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(subview.getWidth(), subview.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
            }
            //bitmaps.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(mainView.getChildAt(i).getWidth(), mainView.getChildAt(i).getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));


        }



        Bitmap tempbitmap = combineImageIntoOne(bitmaps, mainView);

        Bitmap bitmap = tempbitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        mainView.layout(0, 0, mainView.getLayoutParams().width, mainView.getLayoutParams().height);
        Drawable bgDrawable = mainView.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        mainView.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap combineImageIntoOne(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap, RelativeLayout mainView) {
        int w = 0, h = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
            if (i < bitmap.size() - 1) {
                w = bitmap.get(i).getWidth() > bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth() ? bitmap.get(i).getWidth() : bitmap.get(i + 1).getWidth();
            }
            h += bitmap.get(i).getHeight();
        }

        Bitmap temp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(temp);
        int top = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.size(); i++) {
            //Log.d("HTML", "Combine: "+i+"/"+bitmap.size()+1);

            top = (i == 0 ? 0 : top + bitmap.get(i).getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(i), 0f, top, null);
            // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(i), new Matrix(), null);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.get(i+1), 0, 0, null);
        }
        //canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        return temp;
    }

  // This method will get all list items screen shot in one bitmap.
  public Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(ListView p_ListView) {
        ListView listview = p_ListView;
        ListAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter();
        int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
        int allitemsheight = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {
            View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
            childView.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.buildDrawingCache();
            bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
            allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
        //bigcanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight += bmp.getHeight();
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
        }
        //Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;


        return storeImage(bigbitmap);
    }

    //This method will save bitmap and store it in app data and will return a bitmap to the mani method.
    public Bitmap storeImage(Bitmap imageData) {
        // get path to external storage (SD card)
        final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myappxyz";

        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        String fileName = "LastSharedImage.jpg";
        File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
        Log.e("AbosolutePath","==>"+file.getAbsolutePath());


        return bitmap;

    }
```

**ISSUE::** I am getting a final bitmap and passing it to create a pdf or image but final reslut in bothis that my bitmap is coming only for the view which is currently visible even if i get the whole list view screen shot with the method of  getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(ListView p_ListView) by simply passing a listview in it. currently i am getting a screen shot of 10 visible items on screen along with the layout of relative _main view to relative _tablelayout and after that a long white blank space that i think is a space that is occuring due to the remaining listview items that are not visible on the screen but are in the listview this happens even if a scrolled down till the end also. I have trid every method but failed to do so.

**Note::** I have 52 list items in list view and in screen shot only 10-12 listitems are visible which is currently showing in listview.

**Reqiurement**:: Need to resolve this issue on android side only and Do not want to use any third party library for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through below code.

```
private void shareViaPdfOrImage(String selection) {
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        saveBitmap(bitmap, selection);
    }

    private void saveBitmap(Bitmap myBitmap, String selection) {
        final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tallyandroid";

        if (selection.equals("PDF")) {
            createPdf(myBitmap, dirPath);
        } else if (selection.equals("Image")) {
            createImage(myBitmap, dirPath);
        }
    }

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float hight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int convertHighet = (int) hight, convertWidth = (int) width;


        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);


        myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), true);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        document.finishPage(page);


        // write the document content
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
      // Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

        String fileName = "LastImageShared.pdf";
        File filePath = new File(dirPath, fileName);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // close the document
        document.close();

        //sending broadcast to the system file manager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            final Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            final Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
            scanIntent.setData(contentUri);
            sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
        } else {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()));
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }

        File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tallyandroid", fileName);
        sharePdf(outputFile);
    }
    private void shareImg(File dir) {
        try {
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(LedgerTransactionHistoryActivity.this, LedgerTransactionHistoryActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", dir);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void sharePdf(File dir) {
        try {
            progress_dialog.dismiss();
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(LedgerTransactionHistoryActivity.this, LedgerTransactionHistoryActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", dir);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("application/pdf");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

        RelativeLayout mainView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        int childcount = mainView.getChildCount();
        Log.e("childCount", "==>" + childcount);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        //bitmaps.add(getBitmapFromView(mainView));
        height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
            View subview = mainView.getChildAt(i);
            if (subview.getId() != findViewById(R.id.empty_view).getId()) {
                if (subview instanceof SwipeRefreshLayout) {
                    bitmaps.add(getListViewBitmap(listView));
                } else {
                    bitmaps.add(getBitmapFromView(subview));
                }
            }
        }

        Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainView.getMeasuredWidth(), height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
        bigcanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = bitmaps.get(i);
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight += bmp.getHeight();
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
        }
        return bigbitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getListViewBitmap(ListView p_ListView) {
        ListView listview = p_ListView;
        ListAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter();
        int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
        int allitemsheight = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {
            View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
            childView.measure(
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());

            height = height + childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.buildDrawingCache();
            bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
            allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);
        bigcanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight += bmp.getHeight();
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
        }
        return bigbitmap;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        height = height + view.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null) bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Check out this code, if bitmaps are merging or not. In my contexts, it will work for sure.

Comment: thank you sir its working now for both pdf and image